# What exactly does "vcgencmd get_mem arm" display?

Tags: memory-split

If I execute `vcgencmd get_mem gpu` and `vcgencmd get_mem arm` I get the following output:

```
$ vcgencmd get_mem gpu
gpu=76M
$ vcgencmd get_mem arm
arm=948M
```

However this Raspberry Pi has 4 GBytes of RAM. This can be verified looking into `/proc/meminfo`. And `vcgencmd` itself proofs that if I run `vcgencmd get_config int`.

So my question is: What exactly does "vcgencmd get_mem arm" display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/vcgencmd.md):

> Note: On a Raspberry Pi 4 with greater than 1GB of RAM, the arm option is inaccurate. This is because the GPU firmware which implements this command is only aware of the first gigabyte of RAM on the system, so the arm setting will always return 1GB minus the gpu memory value. To get an accurate report of the amount of ARM memory, use one of the standard Linux commands, such as free or cat /proc/meminfo

Comment: Have you submitted this in a *bug report*? :)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: That may be true :)   But as a general (and serious) question, have you submitted bug reports to the Raspbian team previously? If so, were you happy with the way they were handled?

Comment: @Seamus No, I didn't submit any bug reports to the Raspbian team yet.